# Why top right & left corner radius not showing up in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, vstack

When I add `HeadingView()` in code the top left & right corner radius is not showing up

I don't know what is the reason

[image]

```
    struct CustomView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HeadingView()
            Text("Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type ..").padding()
        }
        
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .shadow(color: Color(.red).opacity(0.5), radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
        )
        .padding()
        
        
    }
}

struct HeadingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack(spacing: 9, content: {
                Text("Custom heading")
            })
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 45, maxHeight: 45, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 1, green: 0.75, blue: 0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounded rectangle is added as the `background`, so it is *behind* the yellow rectangle that is `HeadingView`. The non-rounded corners of `HeadingView` covered the rounded corners up.

One way to fix this is to clip the view using `clipShape`, before applying the background.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HeadingView()
    Text("...").padding()
}
// here:
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13))

.background(
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .shadow(...)
)
```

Effectively, this is "cutting off" the unrounded corners of `HeadingView`, so it won't cover the rounded corners of the white background.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please look into this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915225/error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-some-view-to-expected-argument-type-text ?

Comment: When using `clipShape` it makes sense to not use a rounded rectangle for the background. As a rule of thumb, avoid stacking equally rounded objects as their borders won't be clean.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks. I didn’t know it would make a difference.